# Nested for each in java lambda

Tags: java, lambda

This my code for nested foreach,

```
vehicleList.forEach(vehicle->{
              vehicle.getRegionList().forEach(regionList->{

                  // Some DB functions here and passing below details to every iteration 
                  // vehicle.getVehicleId(); 
                  // regionList.getRegionId(); 
                  // regionList.getRegionType();                      

              });
        });
```

Here I have used two forEach loop. Is it possible to achieve my concept with in single forEach.

Comment: you can use `flatMap` to get flat list of regionLists, but then you will lost vehicle information

Comment: It is a nested data structure, so two iterations are natural to do. Why do you want to do it in one?

Comment: it works.. but Nested for each loop with stream want allowed you to better handle exception. better to use for loop in such case.

Comment: IMHO any lambda which is not oneliner is bad.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. instead of using Lambada I will use for loop.

Comment: @KSK please post your solution and accept it so others can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`, then `map` on each inner list's stream:

```
vehicleList.stream()
  .flatMap(v -> v.getRegionList()
       .stream()
       .map(r -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(v, r)))
  .forEach(e -> {
    Vehicle key = e.getKey();
    Region region = e.getValue();
  })
```

The ideal pipeline structure depends heavily on what you're trying to achieve: since you mentioned that you're doing database operations, streams might not be the best option due to checked exceptions.

As a final note, using `forEach` should generally be the last resort, as its use of `Consumer` implies side effects and *most* use cases can be refactored to not use `forEach`.